# Tracking contact form submissions for different pages with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client who has contact forms on 5 different pages.

We would like to track the submissions for each page with Google Analytics in a way that allows to track from which specific page the users submitted.

How is this best set up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement Analytics Event Tracking (E.g. Click on Contact Button).

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Confirmed', 'First ever contact']);">Submit</a>
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

As an alternative, you can add Javascript source code in each contact page. As the simplest posible way, you can install **NoNumber Sourcerer** (http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer), and a snippet like this to associate the event with the button:

```
jQuery( '#ContactButton' ).click(function( event ) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Confirmed', 'First ever contact']);
});
```

Comment: How would we set this up to know from which specific page the form was clicked?

Comment: you can send in different values where 'Contact' and 'Confirmed' are for different pages. Check the documentation in the link NivF007 provided. When I set it up it took some trial and error to get it reporting the way we wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics Event Tracking is the way to go.  Here is a tutorial on how to setup.  You can put the onClick code in the button or input you are using for Submit.

http://www.yellowwebmonkey.com/developer-blog/item/how-to-add-event-tracking-with-google-analytics